# Dispay date formate in Apr 02 in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql="SELECT * 
      FROM events 
      WHERE sdate > CURDATE() 
      ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE (sdate,'%d %F %Y') 
      LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: You should get the data from the database as a regular TIMESTAMP and then do the conversion with PHP.

Comment: But i need only date In Apr 02 format, kindly let us, how to display in above query

Comment: Yes I understand, but it would be easier to covert with PHP instead than SQL.

Comment: Where is your question? This entry lack of question and any research effort. It is unclear what are you trying to achieve and how. Please update your entry.

Comment: $sql="SELECT * FROM events WHERE sdate > CURDATE() ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE (sdate,'%d %F %Y') LIMIT 1";

Answer (score 0):

You will be glad to code using timestamps for this, let me give you an example:

`SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())` will return something like `1586063538`.

That is a timestamp, which is easy to work with.

**Then in your case, you will have to do a 2 step code**

First when retrieving from the database you must use:

```
SELECT field1, field2, ..., fieldN, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(sdate) as epoch
  FROM events 
  WHERE sdate > CURDATE() 
  ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE (sdate,'%d %F %Y') 
  LIMIT 1;
```

where `field1, field2, ...` are the other fields you want and epoch will contain the epoch for that date.
Remember naming the fields is always a good practice when coding.

Then using PHP `date()` function you can parse an epoch timestamp as ***Apr 02*** using:

```
$timestamp = 1586063538;
$day_formatted = date("M d",$timestamp);
echo($day_formatted); //will be Apr 05 in this case
```

More information for the `date()` function in the php documentation here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

If you want to dig deeper on epoch unix timestamps you can look here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time